# How do I split list of strings to list of strings in a list?

Tags: string, list, integer-arithmetic

For example,

```
list1 = ['1 + 1', '2 + 5']
```

becomes,

`split_list = [[1, +, 1],[2, +, 5]]`

I tried

`split_list = [item.split('_') for item in list1]`

which returned [['1 + 1'], ['2 + 5']].
I'm trying to build a function that will rewrite, a list of simple arithmetic problems written in strings, into list of integers and math operators. Maybe I'm going about this wrong way I don't know.

Comment: `split(" ")`, not `split("_") `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
list1 = ['1 + 1', '2 + 5']
[e.split() for e in list1]
```

Result:

```py
[['1', '+', '1'], ['2', '+', '5']]
```

If you want to parse an expression without separators, you need to use standart library [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module, for example so:

```py
parse = lambda f: [s.strip() for s in re.search(r'(\d+)(\D+)(\d+)', f).groups()]
[parse(e) for e in list1]
```

Comment: This works but what if there is no white space between operator and number? like ["1+3",]

Comment: I'm really going to need to learn regular expressions wow! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you always make it + u can do .replace() and replace it and then in the 2 loops to loop throught the loops you make the easy +
Or this is not what you want to do?

Comment: I'm trying to make it with + and - only. So if I have a list of 4 strings like ["1+3","2 - 4", "992 + 12", "12-1"] I want to have 4 separate lists within this list so that I can print each list as a problem set and then print answers by converting each item to integers and math operators.